# kxml doens't parse wbxml to xml correctly

Tags: java, android, parsing, wbxml, kxml

I used to parse a wbxml traffic comes to my android device.
i use kxml parser to print out the contents, but parser says me there isn't any string or attributes to show.
where am i wrong ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, XmlPullParserException, ParserConfigurationException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException, SAXException, TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    File file = new File("path to wbxml file");
    //InputStream in = new FileInputStream("path to wbxml file");
    InputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(in.toString().getBytes());
    WbxmlParser parser = new WbxmlParser();
    parser.setInput(bin, "UTF-8");

    int eventType = parser.getEventType();
    while (eventType != WbxmlParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    if(eventType == WbxmlParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
        //Log.d(a, "Start document");
        System.out.printf("%s\n", "Start document");
    } else if(eventType == WbxmlParser.START_TAG) {
        //Log.d(a, "Start tag "+parser.getName());
        System.out.printf("%s\n", parser.getName());
    } else if(eventType == WbxmlParser.END_TAG) {
        //Log.d(TAG, "End tag " + parser.getName());
        System.out.printf("%s\n", parser.getName());
    } else if(eventType == WbxmlParser.TEXT) {
        //Log.d(TAG, "Text " +parser.getText());
        System.out.printf("%s\n", parser.getText());
    }
    eventType = parser.next();
}
System.out.println("End document");
    //try{

    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.parse(parser);

    //} catch (XmlPullParserException e){
   //     e.printStackTrace();
   // }
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    KXmlSerializer ser = new KXmlSerializer();
    ser.setOutput(out, null);
    doc.write(ser);
    ser.flush();

    byte[] b = out.toByteArray();
    System.out.println(new String(b));
    /*TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tfactory.newTransformer();

    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
    transformer.transform(source, result); */


        }
```

I also checked [Heiner's Blog](http://blog.virtualzone.de/2011/02/creating-parsing-wbxml-with-java-using.html) for answer but nothing...
wbxml document i want to parse is sth like [this](http://pastebin.com/hppQmFd0).

Comment: i wrote a simple program to make a wbxml from xml input file. but using above code again i can't get xml back. \r\n

Comment: i wrote a simple program to make a wbxml from xml input file. but using above code again i can't get xml back. [xmltowbxml](http://pastebin.com/SaTN7xti)